# Is taking Freyd envelopes adjoint to taking stable module categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $T$ be an (idempotent-complete) **triangulated category**. Then the **Freyd envelope** $mod(T)$ is an abelian category, the universal recipient of a homological functor $T \to mod(T)$. The Freyd envelope has enough injectives and enough projectives, and injectives coincide with projectives. I think this makes it roughly what is called a **Frobenius abelian category**. The universal homological functor $T \to mod(T)$ is fully faithful, and its image is precisely the injective / projective objects. (From what I’ve said, it follows that $mod(T)$ is just the category of finitely-presentable additive functors $T^{op} \to Ab$, i.e. the free completion of $T$ under cokernels). Thus the Freyd envelope construction is a functor

$$mod : \{\text{triangulated categories}\} \to \{\text{Frobenius abelian categories}\}$$

Conversely, if $A$ is a Frobenius abelian category, you can construct its **stable module category** by universally killing all maps which factor through a projective/injective object. You get a triangulated category $stmod(A)$, the universal recipient of an additive functor $A \to stmod(A)$ which carries short exact sequences to triangles. Thus the stable module construction is a functor

$$\{\text{triangulated categories}\} \leftarrow \{\text{Frobenius abelian categories}\} : stmod$$

**Question:** Is there any relationship between these two functors in opposite directions? Are they adjoint or something?

Comment: Hi Tim, it would be nice to know a clean relationship between $mod$ and $stmod$. Looks to me like they can't be adjoint to one another. Fix a field $k$, and consider the category $Mod(k)$ of $k$-vector spaces. This is a Frobenius abelian category. Its stable module category is the zero category, so there's no nonzero maps either into or out of $stmod(Mod(k))$. But there are many nonzero additive functors into and out of $Mod(k)$. I think that includes Frobenius abelian categories of the form $mod(T)$ for $T$ triangulated, e.g. $T = D(Mod(k))$. So no adjunction, I guess.